# Changing default font for GUI in bbatsov's prelude

Tags: fonts, prelude

I'm using bbatsov's prelude and I'm trying to change default font for when I'm running a GUI emacsclient window.

I've added the following to my `~/.emacs.d/personal/preludes`:

```
(set-default-font "Source Code Pro-12")
```

And I see the font change if I just start `emacs`.

However, if I restart the `emacs --daemon` I have in the background and ask a GUI window to be opened using `emacsclient -c`, I don't see the default font changed to the one I want.

I've also tried to put that lisp code in a file in `~/.emacs.d/personal/preload/preludes.el` but it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984730/emacs-gui-with-emacs-daemon-not-loading-fonts-correctly). Instead of `set-default-font`, I needed the following:

```
(setq default-frame-alist '((font . "Source Code Pro-12")))
```

Comment: I use emacsclient too and the best way to control fonts is via `~/.Xresources`.

Comment: @KaushalModi: (1) Define "best" (i.e., why?). (2) `~/.Xresources` works only on some platforms.

Comment: @Drew I have jumped through hoops to get the initial font config and frame size right and `~/.Xresources` turned out to be the golden solution, especially with emacsclient. I have noticed that if the font/frame config is in `init.el`, emacs will start up with the default font/frame config and then readjust based on the config in the `init.el`. I agree with your second point though. I should have asked which OS the OP is using. I customize my `~/.Xresources` on Linux (RHEL 6.6).

Comment: FYI, in my case I'm on OSX